# 2 domains on a wordpress site for different pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Suppose I have a wordpress site...

We'll call it www.mysite.com

I then have a page

www.mysite.com/new-page

Supposing I had a second domain name called www.newdomain.com, is it possible to have that sub page of wordpress land at www.mysite.com/new-page (while keeping the address www.newdomain.com)?

And to add to that, supposing I had another page that I wanted to be associated with www.newdomain.com , so lets call it www.newdomain.com/new-page-2

Is all this possible while always keeping the one website/database and how would I go about it?

Thanks for your help, google isnt showing much in terms of my specific problem.

Comment: look into the multi-site functionality.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it's complicated, difficult to maintain / update, and can severely hurt your SEO if you are not extremely delicate about the way you go about it (duplicate content, canonical urls, etc).  It would be much easier and much safer to simply set up the `newdomain.com` pages as redirects to the page on the `mysite.com` domain (but the url in the address bar will change to `mysite.com` after the redirect is in place).